# How can I connect to a API service using curl in php?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to connect to a API service using the following php:

```
$url = 'https://api.wlvpn.com/v2/customers&api-key=my-api-key'
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://127.0.0.1/");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
print_r($curl_error);
```

when I run it I get the following error:

```
couldn't connect to host
```

However, when I run the following command from my command line in ubuntu:

```
jai@ubuntu:/opt/lampp$  curl -u api-key:my-api-key https://api.wlvpn.com/v2/customers
```

I get a response as expected

Can anyone help me what I am missing here
I think I am missing -u option but I dont have any idea how to put it on my php code

Comment: Your url isn't correct. `http://example.com/v2/customers?api-key=my-api-key`

Comment: yes it is https://api.wlvpn.com/v2/customers

Comment: That's not what I meant. You're using && instead of ?.

Comment: Now please see the question with right url but I am not share my api key

Comment: Replace `https://api.wlvpn.com/v2/customers&api-key=my-api-key` with `https://api.wlvpn.com/v2/customers?api-key=my-api-key`

Comment: @jailalawat do you know what `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://127.0.0.1/");` does?

Comment: @LozCheroneツ: Yup, that's the next wrong part.

Comment: Its also https so you should try CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, ill leave @CharlotteDunois to write an answer

Comment: I have set it like this 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);                                         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, TRUE);
and I got this error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: @LozCheroneツ: If the SSL certificate is valid, there is no need to change the values of those two. It's better to leave them to default on a production environment where he transfers (or could transfer) sensitive data.

Comment: CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST expects an integer value. Default is 2.

Comment: Still getting same error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: Try this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your expected answer. The url isn't correct, because you're using & instead of ?. And then you're telling cURL to connect to a proxy on 127.0.0.1 (there is none, usually). And the ssl certificate is self-signed, so you have to set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to 0 and false.

This script works:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://api.wlvpn.com/v2/customers?api-key=my-api-key';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
print_r($curl_error);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks to answer here. It is working fine but response is like this 
{"api_status":0,"error":"Invalid API Key"}

But api key working fine via my console

Comment: One more thing I am add in above code is 
`$url = 'https://api.wlvpn.com/v2/customers?api-key=my-api-key';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
print_r($curl_error);`

Comment: -u stands for user USER:PASSWORD, that means it expects an user and password and not a GET parameter api. Remove the GET parameter and add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api-key:my-api-key");`