# How can I create a customer to a API service using curl in php?

Tags: php, curl

I am succesfully listing all customer data by this post [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056801/how-can-i-connect-to-a-api-service-using-curl-in-php)

I'm trying to create a customer via using API service using the following php:

```
$url = 'https://api.wlvpn.com/v2/customers';
$postData = array("cust_user_id"  => "Jai Lalawat","cust_password" => "12345678","acct_group_id" => 515);
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);#for post request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 'Content-Type: application/json');#for header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api-key:my-api-key");#for -u option authentication
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));#count post data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData); #send post request data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);


$output = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
print_r($curl_error);
?>
```

But I got the following error

```
{"api_status":0,"error":"Invalid account group"}
```

However, when I run the following command from my command line in ubuntu:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -u api-key:my-api-key -d '{"cust_user_id":"jaitest","cust_password":"12345678","acct_group_id":"515"}' https://api.wlvpn.com/v2/customers
```

I get a response as expected

Can anyone help me what I am missing here.

Comment: They're not the same account group. You have 517 in your PHP example and 515 in your command line example

Comment: any customer have same account group

Comment: Both are different account group and that group are exist

Comment: And by the looks of it the command line one you submit json data and the php one you send post data

Comment: in command line it is header and when you see all command it is post request not a get request

Comment: Hello can you please help me if you are free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CLI example you are passing JSON data to the API. You are providing form-data in your PHP example.

You need to pass the data as JSON like in this example:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.wlvpn.com/v2/customers';
$postData = array("cust_user_id"  => "Jai Lalawat","cust_password" => "12345678","acct_group_id" => 515);

$body = json_encode($postData);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($body)
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```